# Splitting a line into three parts using whitespaces in python

Tags: python

I have a line of text, like this:

```
http://www.example.org/lexicon#13797906 http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#gloss an overwhelming number or amount; "a flood of requests"; "a torrent of abuse"
```

And I want to split it into three parts, but just by using the first 2 whitespaces as the point where they should be split. Here is the outcome I am looking for:

```
http://www.example.org/lexicon#13797906 
http://www.monnetproject.eu/lemon#gloss 
an overwhelming number or amount; "a flood of requests"; "a torrent of abuse"
```

I had taught a maxsplit would work but I wasn't sure how to use it in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `str.split` method takes an optional count:

```
text.split(' ', 2)
```